# Can't see a folder people shared with me in my own Dropbox folder

Tags: dropbox

Someone shared a folder with me on Dropbox and I can’t see this folder in my Dropbox folder at home. I have to access it through the Dropbox website.

I thought it was supposed to be visible on every PC that has access to the folder, so people can just copy and paste the files from that folder to their own computer.

Or is it normal that I have to access it through the website?

Comment: Do you use the same account on home pc and through website?

Comment: Check the *Selective Sync* option of your Dropbox application settings.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, but in my case it was purely a misunderstaning of the Dropbox UI.

When you click the link in the email you get when someone shares a folder with you, there is a "Download" button up at the right on the website you come to (see [this screenshot](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TEji0gIDkH8/UVgRVUIi72I/AAAAAAAAIbs/8VJfLwGj5bQ/s1600/link-download-button.jpg)). I thought that button meant that I would download the files once to my local drive – while that is true, it turns out it was also the way to **add the folder** to your Dropbox.

In case you too missed the function of that button, just click it and select "Add to my Dropbox" (again, see [the screenshot](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TEji0gIDkH8/UVgRVUIi72I/AAAAAAAAIbs/8VJfLwGj5bQ/s1600/link-download-button.jpg)).

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the problem by removing the character `:` in the directory name. Then, as the others stated, the directory showed up immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what they said except easier to understand.  I put a period in the name of the folder I was sharing.  Once I changed the folder name so it only consisted of letters, it popped right up.

Comment: Are you saying that some characters in a folder's name prevent it from being shared? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me also. My group partner named the folder Principles of Software Eng. and it wouldn't show up on my Windows dropbox. When I removed the period from the name on the Dropbox site, it immediately synced with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my situation, the cause was the use of vertical bar in the naming of the folders—this is incompatible with Windows.

[Source](https://www.dropbox.com/help/145/en).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and realized after checking on every suggestion on this page that the Dropbox application was not running in the background and therefore was not downloading any new data or changes from online.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the person sharing the folder used a different email for me than the one my DB is filed with. Correct email did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I had the same problem too. Any characters that are not compatible with your OS make the folder not appear. Once those characters are removed, the folder appears immediately.